# Reverse an order of json object keys with values using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = { 
 one : 1, 
 two : 2, 
 three : 3
}
```

I want output like this :

```
let obj ={ 
 three: 3, 
 two : 2, 
 one : 1 
}
```

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);
obj = keys.reverse();
```

Comment: Objects cannot guarantee order - only arrays.

Comment: there is no guarantee on any order of presentation of keys in a js object, especially when converting JSON to JS object hogs system resources

Comment: If order is not important, what's the point of the question?

Comment: I am constructing a new json object via old object so, to make new json object shuffled everytime , I had need this technique

Comment: You confuse. the word JSON refers to `textual syntax`. **It is not a javascript object**. there is no JSON in your question.

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](/q/74479478/4642212) just to repost it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  one : 1, 
 two : 2, 
 three : 3
};

// ️ ['3', '2', '1']
const reversedKeys = Object.keys(obj).reverse();

reversedKeys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, obj[key]); 
});
```

```
const obj = {
  one : 1, 
 two : 2, 
 three : 3
};

// ️ ['3', '2', '1']
const reversedKeys = Object.keys(obj).reverse();

reversedKeys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, obj[key]); 
});
```

Comment: Actually `reversedKeys` would yield `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.entries` to generate an array of `[key,value]` pairs, then use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert it back into an object after reversing.

```js
let obj = { 
 one : 1, 
 two : 2, 
 three : 3
}

let output = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).reverse())

console.log(output)
```